# Setup multiple chrome profiles and pin them to Windows 7 taskbar with different chrome icons

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, user-profiles, pinning

Please, help me regain my sanity.

Can someone write a step-by-step guide on how to set up multiple chrome profiles on a single Windows 7 machines, in a way that will allow me to pin multiple different chrome icons to my taskbar?

I know this is possible, I had this setup working on my two computers. Now, I managed to screw it up on one of them, and just can't get it to work.

This is how I want things to behave:

[image]

I have two completely separate profiles, with different icons. When I click on one of them, it opens, when I click on the other, it opens. No weird icon-changing tricks are happening. Whatever I try to recreate this setup on my other computer has failed, possibly due to [bugs like this one](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=91650). I now just can't use my desktop computer (shared with my wife) due to this problem.

Note that my working solution (on 2nd computer) doesn't use the newer profile system in Chrome, where a small icon is added to Chrome icon (lots of different icons to choose), but rather uses the different icons stored directly in chrome.exe.

Comment: See also https://www.quora.com/Google-Chrome/How-do-I-setup-multiple-chrome-profiles-and-pin-them-to-Windows-7-taskbar-with-different-chrome-icons

Comment: @karan Please re-open. While this happens to be the same topic as the linked question, it's asking something different different. The other question asks how do you create shortcuts to different chrome profiles. this asks how do you pin those shortcuts to the taskbar such that the 2 profiles are treated as separate applications with separate icons by the taskbar.

Comment: i'm not sure if what you want is possible. you can make separate shortcuts, one to each profile, but I haven't found a way to get the taskbar to treat the two shortcuts as separate entities since they both point to the same exe. My workaround was to install Google Chrome Canary alongside Google Chrome. Since they are separate applications, they are separate entities in the taskbar with different icons (the same as in your attached image). if you do this, you don't need to create chrome profiles, though you can still sign-in and sync with your google accounts.

Comment: @dan - it's possible because this is how my work computer is setup, and how my desktop was setup (I set both up myself, I just don't remember how exactly).

Comment: in your screenshot, that looks like the icon for Google Chrome Canary. https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/canary.html  Windows views chrome & canary as 2 separate apps, therefore you get 2 separate icons in the taskbar

Comment: @dan - it may look like canary, but it is not. I manually changed the chrome icon. I promise you, it's the same chrome version. I just verified using http://whatversion.net/chrome/

Comment: Voted to reopen

Comment: that's interesting.. are there any differences between the shortcuts in your taskbar shortcuts, like the values in "target" and "start in"?

Comment: @dan - http://pastebin.com/DXsuaGTj